# Cloud cover percentage of Sentinel2 L1C

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, cloud-cover

The following graph shows the frequency of cloud percentage of a Sentinel-2 L1C tile in 2021, and it seems like only 10 dates have cloudcover less than 10%. I am wondering:

1, How much percentage of cloudcover is considered as "good quality" or "clear" for calculating NDVI directly? If it's 10%, then there are actually only a few images that can be used.

2, For those images with a high cloudcover percentage, how could we do the "cloud masking" to get rid of the cloud effect using QGIS (or python)?

[image]

Comment: There are more factors that affect and you should take in account.
In the first place the date of the images capture, in the graph (I think) you have those for a whole year, but for the observation of a crop you will need images of specific dates.
On the other hand, the captured surface, the percentage of clouds is for the entire image, but normally the area to study is not it. A low percentage of clouds can be all in your area of ​​interest or a high percentage leave it free.
I recommend you that before starting work in QGIS you quickly check the images in an online viewer.

Comment: @JLR thanks for your quick reply! Let me clarify that, in the graph I show the whole year, because my goal is to do the temporal analysis to see how NDVI changes during different seasons. That's why I didn't choose a specific date. On the other hand, my interest area is one whole country not a small region, so I take the whole tile. In this case, how much percentage of couldcover of the image do you think is a good idea to take?

Comment: Maybe you could go for a composite? This is what is done with [MODIS](https://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/mod13.php) for instance. Per pixel, you can select the highest NDVI value over a time period.

Comment: It depends on the country and your needs.
Being for such a large area (complete tiles) you will have to put a relatively high one, 20-25% for example. I insist that it depends on the area of ​​the world. I've worked with images of coastal areas that at 50% had the entire land surface cleared, if you have large coastal areas keep this in mind. In others, a certain region of Uruguay, it has been impossible for me to get a single useful image.

Answer (score 1):

The scene classification product, a result of [Sen2Cor](https://step.esa.int/main/snap-supported-plugins/sen2cor/), contains pixel information about clouds.

There is also an open source cloud/cloud shadow classifcation which runs in python [FMASK](https://www.pythonfmask.org/en/latest/).

Comment: the scene classification product - do you mean the Sentinel level2A product? But if I would love to do a temporal analysis that considers images from 2015 to nowadays, I suppose I need to use level1C products right? Since level2A data is only available after 2017. (I will check the FMASK package, thank you so much!)

Comment: @yongyuuu Yes, try downloading one of the L2A and see what's inside.